# jquery-inline editing of html table content

Tags: jquery

in this table onclick i want to make complete row editable.but with the below code am able edit only cell at a time.i.e, when i click on the row,the complete cells in tr should be editable.

```js
$("#tableid").on("click", "td", function() {

  $(this).parents('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
  var new = $(this).text();
  $(this).addClass("editclass");
  $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + new + "'/>");

  $(this).children().first().focus();

  $(this).children().first().keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var new1 = $(this).val();
      $(this).parent().text(new1);
      $(this).parent().removeClass("editclass");
    }
  });
  $(this).children().first().blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().text(new);
    $(this).parent().removeClass("editclass");
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>sno</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>language</th>
      <th>state</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: There's no `td` in your example table.

Comment: If you want all the `TD`s in the row to be editable, you need to set the HTML of `$(this).siblings()`, not just `$(this)`.

Comment: @Barmar am getting td values dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the HTML of all the sibling TDs, not just the one they clicked on.

Also, don't use `new` as a variable name, it's a Javascript reserved word.

I added a `click` handler for the newly added inputs that stops event bubbling. Otherwise, when you click on a field, it bubbles out to the `td`, and runs the handler again.

```js
$("#tableid").on("click", "td", function() {

  $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
  $(this).siblings().addBack().html(function(i, oldhtml) {
    return "<input type='text' value='" + oldhtml + "'/>";
  }).addClass("editclass").find("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      var new1 = $(this).val();
      $(this).parent().text(new1);
      $(this).parent().removeClass("editclass");
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    var new1 = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().text(new1);
    $(this).parent().removeClass("editclass");
  }).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(this).find("input").focus();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>sno</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>language</th>
      <th>state</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Some Name</td>
      <td>ID#1</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: when i edit the td its gvng the complete html in the editable td cell

Comment: Did you add the `click` handler at the end? I was getting the HTML until I did that.

Comment: Instead of changing them to `<input>`, why don't you use `contenteditable` attribute?

Comment: yeah i added click handler

Comment: I don't know why you're getting different results than me. Do you see that when you run my snippet, or just when you copy the answer to your application?